# Uploading image from Android to Firebase always gives exception

Tags: java, android, image-uploading, firebase-storage

I'm developing an app that accesses all the images in your device and automatically upload the images on Firebase Storage.
This is like whenever the activity starts, it automatically fetch image and upload without user's selection.

**Main_Activity**:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.OnProgressListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;

import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private Cursor cursor;
    private int columnIndex;
    GridView AllImages;
    public int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS = 123;
    Uri myUri;
    ImageView img;


    FirebaseApp firebaseApp;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage;
    StorageReference storageReference;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            if ((ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) && (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))) {

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("Else", "Else");
        }

        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.images);

        ArrayList<String> arrayList = getImagesPath(this);
        String a = arrayList.get(6);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + a.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        img.setImageURI(Uri.parse(new File(a).toString()));

        myUri = Uri.parse(new File(c).toString());

        firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.getInstance();
        firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance(firebaseApp);
        storageReference = firebaseStorage.getReference("Pictures");

        StorageReference sRef = storageReference.child(Constants.STORAGE_PATH_UPLOADS + System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getFileExtension(myUri));
         sRef.putFile(myUri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Uploaded ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                        // ...
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can't Upload ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                })
        .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                // Setting progressDialog Title.
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Uploading ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });



        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID};

        cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID + "");
        columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);

        AllImages = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.GV_Images);
        AllImageAdapter adapter = new AllImageAdapter(MainActivity.this, cursor, columnIndex);
        AllImages.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    public String getFileExtension(Uri uri) {
        ContentResolver cR = getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));


    }


    public static ArrayList<String> getImagesPath(Activity activity) {
        Uri uri;
        ArrayList<String> listOfAllImages = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor cursor;
        int column_index_data, column_index_folder_name;
        String PathOfImage = null;
        uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        String[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME };

        cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null,
                null, null);

        column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            PathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index_data);

            listOfAllImages.add(PathOfImage);

        }
        return listOfAllImages;

    }


}
```

**Adapter Class**:

```
public class AllImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context c;
    Cursor cur;
    ImageView imageView;
    int columnIndex;
    public AllImageAdapter(Context c, Cursor cur, int columnIndex)
    {
        this.c = c;
        this.cur = cur;
        this.columnIndex = columnIndex;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return cur.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Set The Image in Image View.
        imageView = new ImageView(c);
        cur.moveToPosition(position);
        int imageID = cur.getInt(columnIndex);
        imageView.setImageURI(Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + imageID));

        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(330, 330));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        imageView.setPadding(4, 4, 4, 4);
        //convertView.setTag(imageView);
        return imageView;
    }

}
```

In (`Main Activity`), for a time being, I'm just picking one picture by myself that is on index 6, to check if it works or not.

And here's

**my another class**:

```
public class Constants {


    public static final String STORAGE_PATH_UPLOADS = "uploads/";
    //public static final String DATABASE_PATH_UPLOADS = "uploads";
}
```

I'm not using Database yet.
The problem that I'm facing is, whenever the program runs, it shows exception:
`StorageException` has occurred.

```
An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
09-08 12:06:44.694 11024-11263/com.example.umairasher.picturestofirebase 
E/StorageException: No content provider: received_1035650876484715.jpeg
                                                                                                 java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: received_1035650876484715.jpeg
                                                                                                     at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1092)
                                                                                                     at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:944)
                                                                                                     at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:664)
                                                                                                     at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                     at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.putFile(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                     at com.example.umairasher.picturestofirebase.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:113)
                                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6439)
                                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2498)
                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2605)
                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:165)
                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
                                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:179)
                                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5730)
                                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
                                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:681) 


E/StorageException: No content provider: received_1035650876484715.jpeg

    java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: received_1035650876484715.jpeg
                                                                                                         at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1092)
                                                                                                         at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:944)
                                                                                                         at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:664)
                                                                                                         at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                         at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.putFile(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                         at com.example.umairasher.picturestofirebase.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:113)
                                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6439)
                                                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2498)
                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2605)
                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:165)
                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
                                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:179)
                                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5730)
                                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
                                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:681)
```

Can anybody please help, I know I'm doing a mistake somewhere but just can't help it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It always goes into exception. First Toast shows the path of image, and next shows 'Cant Upload'.

Comment: @Facing same issue. Did you get any solution?

Comment: @Shruti No, I haven't got any solution yet.